# subtract one minute from datetime in powerbuilder

Tags: powerbuilder, powerbuilder-conversion

I have seen a lot of info on how to subtract one datetime from the other and how to add years on to a datetime. but the following is giving me a headache.
How to subtract 1 minute from date in powerbuilder?please help and support.

Thanks & Regards
Rahul G

Answer (score 1):

if you are using powerbuilder.net you can do it in 2 line of code:

```
System.DateTime newDate
newDate =  System.DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how it is done in PowerScript. It would be easier if you did it in SQL using the DateAdd function.

DateTime ldt_thedate, ldt_newdate
Time lt_thetime

// get the current date-time
ldt_thedate = DateTime(Today(), Now())

// subtract 1 minute
lt_thetime = RelativeTime(Time(ldt_thedate), -1)

// assemble the date-time
ldt_newdate = DateTime(Date(ldt_thedate), lt_thetime)

Comment: Hai , Thank You for your reply.It is working but if the date is 22-sep-2014 00:00:00.

Comment: You can use the DateAdd SQL function in an inline statement. It will be less code and won't have the midnight issue.

Comment: If you need to do this a lot you could create a SQL function with the datepart as a parameter and then use it to subtract whatever you need to from a date.